# Using sed or grep to search and replace ip address in the file

Tags: sed, grep

I have used this code it only enter with new ipaddress

```
sed -r 's/(\b[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b'/$newip/
```

But i need to enter with system ipaddress to the file directly,can anyone help it out with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file and also sample output expected.

Comment: Need to enter with system ip address 192.168.0.20 .This ip address 192.168.0.20 need to enter into the file. 

                                                                              
                                                                              
echo ip addr | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" config.json

tired out with this comment but it is not entering with ip address inside the file

Comment: Not able to understand your comment. Can you provide a sample input file and also sample output expected

Comment: This is file `{
  "MONGODB_CONNECTION_URL" : "mongodb://127.0.0.1/genieacs",
  "CWMP_INTERFACE" : "0.0.0.0",
  "CWMP_PORT" : 7547,
  "CWMP_SSL" : false,
  "NBI_INTERFACE" : "0.0.0.0",
  "NBI_PORT" : 7557,
  "FS_INTERFACE" : "0.0.0.0",
  "FS_PORT" : 7567,
  "FS_HOSTNAME" : "acs.example.com",
  "DEBUG" : false
}`  I need to enter with system ip address inside this file using sed command instead of 0.0.0.0 i need to enter with 192.168.0.20 .

Answer (score 0):

The command you have already does this. Just need to add the -i option to the sed:

```
$ cat file
{ "MONGODB_CONNECTION_URL" : "mongodb://127.0.0.1/genieacs",
  "CWMP_INTERFACE" : "0.0.0.0",
  "CWMP_PORT" : 7547,
  "CWMP_SSL" : false,
  "NBI_INTERFACE" : "0.0.0.0",
  "NBI_PORT" : 7557,
  "FS_INTERFACE" : "0.0.0.0",
  "FS_PORT" : 7567,
  "FS_HOSTNAME" : "acs.example.com",
  "DEBUG" : false
}
```

2. Set the IP address in a variable:

`$ newip="192.168.0.20"`

3. Run the sed command:

`$ sed -i -r 's/(\b[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b'/$newip/ file`

4. File has updated IP:

`$ cat file
{ "MONGODB_CONNECTION_URL" : "mongodb://255.255.25.0/genieacs",
  "CWMP_INTERFACE" : "255.255.25.0",
  "CWMP_PORT" : 7547,
  "CWMP_SSL" : false,
  "NBI_INTERFACE" : "255.255.25.0",
  "NBI_PORT" : 7557,
  "FS_INTERFACE" : "255.255.25.0",
  "FS_PORT" : 7567,
  "FS_HOSTNAME" : "acs.example.com",
  "DEBUG" : false
}`

Comment: I have tired with this command  `sed -i -r 's/(\b[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b'/$192.168.0.28/config.json` but i am getting the error 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 46: unknown option to `s'` . And it should not change for mongodb ip only it should change in cwmp,nbi and fs.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/([^/])\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b([^/])'/\1192.168.0.28\2/g config.json
```

if as variable e.g. obtained from `ifconfig` etc, after testing do real editing, add `-i` option

```
$ newip=192.168.0.28
$ sed -Ei 's/([^/])\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b([^/])'/\1$newip\2/g config.json
```

Comment: I should get the output like this, `${
  "MONGODB_CONNECTION_URL" : "mongodb://127.0.0.1/genieacs",
  "CWMP_INTERFACE" : "192.168.0.28",
  "CWMP_PORT" : 7547,
  "CWMP_SSL" : false,
  "NBI_INTERFACE" : "192.168.0.28",
  "NBI_PORT" : 7557,
  "FS_INTERFACE" : "192.168.0.28",
  "FS_PORT" : 7567,
  "FS_HOSTNAME" : "acs.example.com",
  "DEBUG" : false
}`

Comment: When entering with this command `sed -Ei 's/(\b[0-9]{1,3}\.?){4}\b'/$newip/g config.json`  getting the output like this                                               `${
  "MONGODB_CONNECTION_URL" : 
  "mongodb://192.168.0.28/genieacs",
  "CWMP_INTERFACE" : "192.168.0.28",
  "CWMP_PORT" : 192.168.0.28,
  "CWMP_SSL" : false,
  "NBI_INTERFACE" : "192.168.0.28",
  "NBI_PORT" : 192.168.0.28,
  "FS_INTERFACE" : "192.168.0.28",
  "FS_PORT" : 192.168.0.28,
  "FS_HOSTNAME" : "acs.example.com",
  "DEBUG" : false
}`